# Textbox is reference to another Textbox, need to return the value of whats in the second textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

There is probably a simple solution to this, but it is eluding me.

I have a textbox (name = CFMon), that references a month textbox. The user will submit values for all months, but they select a key month that is used for a calculation. I need to use their selected key month to get the value from the appropriate month textbox (each month is named mon1, mon2, etc)

When not using VBA, I would simply use the indirect function to evaluate all of the string.

```
test = Forms![Form]![CFMon] & ".value"
```

this does exactly what it is supposed to do and just regurgitate the text string

I am hoping the evaluate the reference and return the appropriate month value. For Example. The user selects CFMon = Mon3, the value will return the value the user inputs in the Mon3 (March) textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could obtain the control from the Controls collection, e.g.:

```
test = Forms("Your Form Name").Controls(Forms![Form]![CFMon]).Value
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`eval`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/eval-function-8c4a1b10-85ba-40db-b0c8-5290da4d4166) function, but I would advise against this:

```
test = eval("Forms![Your Form Name]![" & Forms![Form]![CFMon] & "].Value")
```

Comment: The controls method works. Thank you! I am happy to learn that